# How to move \fbox vertically, or how to frame \vbox or \vtop and move it vertically (through the baseline) without changing the size of the box?

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes, fbox

I need to be able to move a \vtop or \vbox vertically without changing the box size, but it gets stuck at the baseline (you can pad the contents of the box up or down but you can't seem to move the box itself away from the baseline in any vertical direction).

Since I need to visually keep track of the size of the box, I enclose the box inside an \fbox. Let's take the following code as a starting point.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\fboxrule0.1pt
\fboxsep0pt

\begin{document}
  \newbox\hX
  \setbox\hX\hbox{X}
  \fbox{x}\fbox{\vbox{\copy\hX}}
  % how to move second \fbox such that capital x slides up or down without changing vertical size of the \fbox frame?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hmf0.png)? If not, please show an approximate drawing of what you need.

Comment: By the way, is there a particular reason for the `\vbox`? A `\vbox` containing a single `\hbox` is useless and the `\hbox` is sufficient. If the `\hbox` contains a single character, then you can use just the character.

Comment: as you are using color things would be a _lot_ safer if you used `\sbox\hx{..}` rather than `\setbox\hx\hbox{...}`  as you have it it happens to be safe but if you coloured the X.....

Comment: @egreg, yes, something like that.

Comment: @egreg, I thought only vertical boxes can be moved up or down.

Comment: @bp2017 the difference between a vbox and hbox relates to how its content is arranged. there is essentially no difference in its external behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `\fbox` is just to keep track of the size, you should set `\fboxsep` to the negative of `\fboxrule`.

Use `\raisebox`.

By the way, `\setbox\hX=\hbox{X}\vbox{\copy\hX}}` is a complicated way to get the same as typing `X`. The only difference is that you don't start horizontal mode, but that's irrelevant in the context where you use it.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}

\newcommand{\movebox}[2][0pt]{\raisebox{#1}{\fbox{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\movebox{x}\movebox[-5pt]{X}\movebox{x}\movebox[-\height]{X}

\end{document}
```

Within the argument to `\raisebox` you can use `\height` and `\depth` that refer to the natural height and depth of the box that's being moved. Of course `\movebox{x}` is the same as typing `x`, but I used it for uniformity.

[image]

#### TeXnical note.

LaTeX's command `\raisebox` relies on the TeX primitive `\raise`, whose syntax is

`\raise`⟨dimen⟩⟨box⟩

where ⟨dimen⟩ is any legal dimension (explicit or an optional factor followed by a `\dimen` or `\skip` register, in the latter case coerced to a `\dimen` by removing the stretch and shrink components) and ⟨box⟩ is any box specification:

- `\hbox`⟨optional `to` or `spread`⟩`{`⟨horizontal material⟩`}`
- `\vbox`⟨optional `to` or `spread`⟩`{`⟨vertical material⟩`}`
- `\vtop`⟨optional `to` or `spread`⟩`{`⟨vertical material⟩`}`
- `\box`⟨register number⟩ or `\copy`⟨register number⟩
- `\lastbox`

The ⟨box⟩ can be any type of box. The `\raise` operation just moves down its reference point (up if the dimension argument is negative) by the specified amount and fixes the height and depth of the constructed box accordingly.

The restriction is that `\raise` *cannot* be used in vertical mode. There is also `\lower` that works symmetrically; `\lower10pt` is the same as `\raise-10pt` and conversely.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand well what you want, `\raisebox` does it very simply:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\fboxrule0.1pt
\fboxsep0pt

\begin{document}

  \newbox\hX
  \setbox\hX\hbox{X}
  \fbox{x}\raisebox{\dimexpr1ex+0.2pt}{\fbox{\vbox{\copy\hX}}}\raisebox{-0.35\height}{\fbox{\vbox{\copy\hX}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. What is the value of `\height`? How did you know that `0.35` of it would make the 3rd box top aligned with the 1st box?

Comment: `\height` is measured by TeX. The value of `0.35` was found by trial and error – it may depend on the letter having descenders or not.

Comment: Is measured from the box to be raised? Interesting.

Comment: It is a powerful command. You also, with optional arguments, make LaTeX believe it has the height and depth you choose.

Comment: @Sigur all latex box commands have `\height` `\depth` `\width`, you can make something take twice the space with `\makebox[\2\width]{...}` etc.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I didn't know that. Very useful, I'm sure.